# Append Items to list of dict from xml

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I thought this was easy, but for some reason, not able to append dict within the list. Overwriting previous data.

```
for child in data.find_all("item"):
    if "Traffic" in  child.find("name").string:
       self.output["Name"] = child.find("name").string
       self.output["LastValue"] = child.find("lastvalue").string
       self.results.append(self.output)

print(self.results)
```

Here is the following output

```
data = """
<item>
<name>In</name>
<lastvalue>5,000 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>
<item>
<name>Out</name>
<lastvalue>155 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>
<item>
<name>Total</name>
<lastvalue>5,000 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>
```

I tried running the code, but it always prints the last item.
as it is overwriting the previous data.

```
output = [{"Name": "In", "LastValue": "5,000 MByte",
           "Name": "Out", "LastValue": "5,000 MByte",
           "Name": "Total", "LastValue": "5,000 MByte"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip()` function to zip values from `<name>` and `<lastvalue>`. Then use dict comprehension:

```
data = """<item>
<name>In</name>
<lastvalue>5,000 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>
<item>
<name>Out</name>
<lastvalue>155 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>
<item>
<name>Total</name>
<lastvalue>5,000 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

results = []
results.append( {name.text: lastvalue.text for name, lastvalue in zip(soup.select('name'), soup.select('lastvalue'))} )

print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[{'In': '5,000 MByte', 'Out': '155 MByte', 'Total': '5,000 MByte'}]
```

EDIT: If there are more `<lastvalue>`:

```
data = """<item>
<name>In</name>
<lastvalue>5,000 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>
<item>
<name>Out</name>
<lastvalue>155 MByte</lastvalue>
<lastvalue>10,100 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>
<item>
<name>Total</name>
<lastvalue>5,000 MByte</lastvalue>
</item>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

results = []

for name in soup.select('name'):
    results.append(
        {name.text: [lv.text for lv in name.find_next_siblings('lastvalue')]}
    )

print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[{'In': ['5,000 MByte']},
 {'Out': ['155 MByte', '10,100 MByte']},
 {'Total': ['5,000 MByte']}]
```

Comment: i was using `channelsoup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")` thank you

Comment: @miu It will work with `lxml` too, I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive list, Should use select or find

Comment: what if there are two `lastvalue` like to add to list

Comment: @miu The values in the dictionary will then become lists and will hold two values from `<lastvalue>`. You can use for example `collections.defaultdict` https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.

Comment: I tried following:
```
    for name, lastvalue in soup.find_all("item"):
        if name.text not in results:
            output["Name"] = name.text
            output["Lastvalue"] = lastvalue.text
            results[name].append(output)
```

Comment: Is the the `find_next_siblings` is a function.. thanks learned a lot

Comment: Sorry, noticed, each keys are its new dict, is there any way to combine it?
`[{"Discards in": ["0 #", "0 #/s"], "Discards out": ["0 #", "0 #/s"]}`

Comment: @miu Yes, but it's better to ask new question here in SO. These comments are not good place for that.